# the smallest transfinite ordinal number

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

My guess is that $\omega$ is the smallest transfinite ordinal number. To prove this, let $\beta$ be any transfinite ordinal number and let $\operatorname{ord}(B, \le)= \beta$. And I need to show that the usual ordering of natural numbers is order isomorphic to a segment of $B$. But I'm having trouble proving this. How can I show this?

Comment: What does $\operatorname{ord}(B,\leq)$ mean?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** If an ordinal is infinite, then it has finite initial segments of every possible length.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate a little bit more please?

Comment: Ordinals are well-ordered.  Which comes first, a finite ordinal or a transfinite ordinal?

Comment: @user135204: If $(B,\leq)$ is an infinite well-ordered set, then for every finite $n$, there is an initial segment which has exactly $n$ elements.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: This is how I used your hint. Define $f: N -> B$ such that for each $n$ $f(n)=b$, where $B_b$is the segment of $B$ which has exactly $n$ elements. Then this is a well-defined, injective, strictly increasing function. So $\omega$ is order-isomorphic to a segment of $B$. Is this correct?

Comment: @user135204: Yes, that is correct. But you have to prove my hint as well, if you don't know why it is true.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I tried to prove that using mathematical induction. Since $B$ is well-ordered, it has least element $b_1$, then ${b_1}$ is a segment with a single element. Suppose for $k$ there is $b_k$ such that $B_{b_k}$ has $k$ elements. Then, since every element but the last in a well-ordered set has an immediate successor, there is an immediate successor to $b_k$, say $b_{k+1}$. Then, $B_{b_{k+1}}$ has $k+1$ elements. Thus, by mathematical induction, it is true. Is this proof correct?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Also, you seem to be majoring in set theory and I'm currently studying the subject on my own. I'm almost finished with the book set theory, an intuitive approach by You Feng Lin. What book would you recommend next for me to study? Thanks.

Comment: @user135204: That seems correct. What's next? I'd try Enderton's Elements of Set Theory; if you are looking to advance into axiomatic set theory, perhaps some more basic logic would be a good start, Halbeisen's Combinatorial Set Theory has some introduction to logic as well axiomatic set theory. If you already know basics of logic (say, up to the completeness theorem, and basics of the incompleteness theorem) maybe Jech Set Theory or Kunen's Set Theory would make a good path towards axiomatic set theory.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer. I assume from the discussion that "transfinite=infinite".
Just remark that if $\alpha$ is finite then $\alpha+1$ is finite. So if $\beta$ is infinite then all finite ordinals are less than $\beta$. This means that $\omega \leq \beta$. $\omega$ being defined as the set of finite ordinals.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are interested, it is also proved by Whitehead & Russell at ✳ 263.5 in *Principia Mathematica*

[image]

Which says if  $P$ is an infinite well-ordered series, $P$ confined to the terms at a finite distance from the first term of P is a progression($\omega$). It follows that an infinite ordinal is at least as great as $\omega$, and therefore infinite ordinals other than $\omega$ are greater than $\omega$.*

- Whitehead & Russell. *Principia Mathematica*, Volume 3. Merchant Books, 1913